# Highchart Series are displayed one after another and not parallel

Tags: highcharts

Are you having a nice day?

I have this challenge with my Highchart.

[image: Highchart]

The series are displayed one after another and not parallel.

This is the output from my JSON_Array. Instead of 2013-08-02 13:30:40 the time-values are displayed in microtime-format. It is just for better explaining.

**So wth can be wrong, that the series are displayed one after another?**

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){   
    $.getJSON('micro-grid_data.php', 
    function(data) { 
    Highcharts.setOptions({ global: { useUTC: false } }); 
    chart = new Highcharts.StockChart
    ({
    chart:  {  renderTo: 'container' , zoomType: 'x',   type: 'line', width: 900 },  
         legend: { enabled: true, verticalAlign:'bottom' },
    navigator: { enabled: false  },
    title:  { text: 'You see the data of the last measured hour!' },  
    credits: { enabled: false  },
    plotOptions: {  series: { marker : { enabled: false, states: {  hover: { enabled: true  }  }   } }   },
    xAxis: {  type: 'datetime', title: { text: 'time'  } }, 
    rangeSelector:{ enabled: false },
    yAxis:   { title: { text: '' , style: { color : '#4572A7' } } },     
    tooltip: { xDateFormat: '%e. %b.%Y  %H:%M:%S', valueDecimals: 2  }, 
     series:   [ { name: 'consumer' , data: data[0]} ,  { name: 'producer' , data: data[1]}],
    exporting: { enabled: true },
    });  
    // Format the y-data.
    Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2, '.', ',');
});
});


// Redraw the chart. 
function redraw()
{    
// Get variables from configuration settings area.
var startdate = $('#<?php echo $startdatewithout ?>').val();
var enddate = $('#<?php echo $enddatewithout ?>').val();
var range =  $('#range').val();


  /* New data is loaded via AJAX-call.
   * Output is an JSON-Array, Example: [[1,2],[20,3]].
   * If success the new data is set in the chart and the screen will be unhide.
   */
  $.ajax({      
    url: "micro-grid_data.php?string=<?php echo $string; ?>&range="+range+"&startdate="+startdate+"&enddate="+enddate+"&reload=1",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(datareload) {  // Set new data in chart.                      
                     chart.series[0].setData(datareload[0]);  
                     chart.series[1].setData(datareload[1]);  
                         // Unhide the screen.
                     chart.hideLoading();
                    },
  });
};
return false;
};
```

Comment: Susanne, I had assumed that there maybe something wrong with the conversion from human readable to unix time and back, but @jlbriggs observation is correct, the time stamp even in unix format is consecutive, so the second series is correctly plotted after the first one the time line, if that is not intended then there is a logic error in the code that assigns the time to the second series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Odds are there is something wrong with your time format for the second series.

It's always better to show what you are actually using rather than converting the time to a human readable format just for showing it here.  Tough to troubleshoot anything if you aren't showing the exact way it's currently set up.

Comment: Hello! I changed the code output into what I really get! Thanks for the advice! Your susan

Comment: The date and time of the **last** time stamp in your **first** series:

    **Wed Jun 12 2013 05:12:04** GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time)

-

The date and time of the **first** time stamp in your **second** series:

    **Wed Jun 12 2013 05:16:53** GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time)

So the chart is drawing it exactly as it should, by the look of it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I recognized that the normal-time is written correctly into database, but the timestamp not :( That was the error! Thanks for helping me! Wish you the best!